# Not able to install plugins in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, rackspace

I've a **wordpress** hosted in **Rackspace** cloud server. The site is  working fine. To access the wordpress admin panel i have setup FTP access to the root user. I'm able to access and create files via FTP and the wordpress admin can connect to the server via FTP.

But i'm not able to install new plugins from the **wordpress** admin panel.I'm getting the following errors.

> Downloading install package from https://downloads.wordpress.org/plugin/icon-list.0.3.zip…
>
> Unpacking the package…
>
> Could not create directory.
>
> Return to Plugin Installer

First i thought it was some permission issue. But in the server i've set the permissions 777 to the wordpress project folder.But its still showing the same error.

Is there any configuration change made, to be able to install the wordpress plugins successfully.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the `write` permission for your FTP user.

> Read `Wordpress` file `permissions` from here [Changing_File_Permissions](https://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_File_Permissions)

Answer (score 0):

It's can be also a problem with web hosting configurations. Try the FTP method. [Reference here.](https://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_wp-config.php#WordPress_Upgrade_Constants)

Add the following lines in your **wp-config.php**

```
define('FS_METHOD', 'ftpext');
define('FTP_USER', 'YOUR FTP LOGIN');
define('FTP_PASS', 'YOUR FTP PASSWORD');
define('FTP_HOST', 'YOUR FTP HOST (without http:// or ftp://)');
define('FTP_SSL', false);
```

Another way :
Your web server has write permissions, then add this to your **wp-config.php** file:

```
define('FS_METHOD', 'direct');
```

Also, wanted to add that you must NEVER set the **wp-content** permission or permission of any folder to 777.